# Retrieve cached jquery elements

Tags: jquery, performance

I am caching jquery elements like this

```
var $stepList = $('#stepList > li');
var $tableRowList = $('.tablesorter-js tbody > tr');

//and use them in the function
pages = {
    buildDetail: function ($stepList, $tableRowList) {
          console.log($stepList, $tableRowList)
    });
}
// this function is invoked many times
pages.buildDetail($stepList, $tableRowList);
```

Is there a more efficient way to cache and retrieve elements, since I will have many more cached elements in buildDetail() ?

Comment: there is no need to use `$(stepList)` in the `buildDetail` as `stepList` already is a jQuery wrapper object

Comment: If you use the convention `$jQueryObjectName = $(.....);` you can remember that they are already jQuery objects

Comment: I updated the question. What I want to do is retrieve all cached elements in buildDetail() at once...

Comment: As you have declared $stepList as a global, you shouldn't need to pass it into buildDetail - you should be able to just reference it from within the function, also when you call the function at the end, you are passing in a couple of variables that are unassigned

Comment: Sorry for my inconvenience. The function buildDetail is in a namespace as you can see in my update. Im using requireJS. So the variables is declared outside pages.buildDetail()